# Why does sampling of diffusion model diverge?

Tags: sampling

I'm encountering a divergence problem with the sampling process in my diffusion model, which I'm using to impute missing data (time-series). My model is based on Diffwave, CSDI, and DDPM with some modifications. Despite my efforts to adjust parameters and model architecture, the sampling process continues to diverge. I'm uncertain about the causes of this divergence issue and whether the problem lies within my sampling code or if there are other factors contributing to it.

1. is there any problem with the sampling code below? I used the sampling method of DDPM.
2. if 1 is not, why does sampling of model diverge? any potential reason??

Here is my code and parameters.

beta schedule is linspace from 0.0001 to 0.02 with 1000 steps.

```
self.beta_min = 0.0001
self.beta_max = 0.02
self.n_steps = 1000

self.betas = torch.linspace(self.beta_min, self.beta_max, self.n_steps).to(device)

self.alphas = 1-self.betas
self.alpha_bars = torch.Tensor([torch.prod(self.alphas[:i+1]) for i in range(len(self.alphas))]).to(device)
```

```
def forward_process(self, x0 : torch.Tensor, t):
    # Make x_t, using x0 and t
    return (self.alpha_bars[t]**0.5) * x0 + ((1-self.alpha_bars[t])**0.5)*torch.randn_like(x0)
```

```
def sample(self, observed_data, cond_mask, mask_ta):
        current_sample = torch.randn(self.length, self.feature).to(device)
        
        coeff1 = (1/(self.alphas))**0.5
        coeff2 = (1-self.alphas)/((1-self.alpha_bars)**0.5)
            
        for t in range(self.n_steps-1, -1, -1):
            predicted = self.forward(current_sample, observed_data, cond_mask, t, mask_ta)
            current_sample = coeff1[t] * (current_sample - coeff2[t] * predicted)

            if t != 0:
                sigma = ((1-self.alpha_bars[t-1])*self.betas[t]/(1-self.alpha_bars[t]))**0.5
                current_sample = current_sample + sigma*torch.randn_like(current_sample).to(device)
        
        return current_sample * mask_ta
```

figure below is one of sampling results.
red line is sampling result and green one is target data which is normalized.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQdnS.png)